# How to append (;) to a string in a autocomplete text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a autocomplete extender and have a list from which suggestions are given, I am allowing user to enter more than 1 value seperated by a semicolon (;). And do the string split

```
string[] result =  txt_to.Text.Split(';');
```

after entering one value user has to enter ; so that he can enter the second value, How can I automatically enter a ; after every value is selected so that the user can just type the second value without entering ;

```
 <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_to"
                            MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="10" CompletionSetCount="3" EnableCaching="true"
                            FirstRowSelected="true" UseContextKey="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
                            DelimiterCharacters=";" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add 2 handlers. One when the 'enter' key is pressed (if the user selects the value using the keyboard) and an other when the use select a value with his mouse. 
at the handlers append the ; at the textbox.

hope that helped...

try this

add at your extender: OnClientItemSelected ="addSemiColumn"

add these 2 javascripts to your page:

```
function GetKeyPress(){
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13){
        document.getElementById ('txt_to').value +=";"; 
    }
}


 function addSemiColumn(){
     document.getElementById ('txt_to').value +=";"; 
}
```

and this to your code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack Then
        txt_to.Focus()
    End If
    txt_to.Attributes.Add("OnKeyPress", "GetKeyPress()")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show some code for it, will be helpful for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you select value and before set this value to textbox just add ";" to that selected value and then set in textbox.

Thanks
Jinesh Jain